# PHP ВК Бот не отвечает на сообщения

Tags: php, вконтакте, heroku

Ошибок не выдает, работает через Heroku.

```
<?php

require('../vendor/autoload.php');

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

// Register the monolog logging service
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
  'monolog.logfile' => 'php://stderr',
));



$app->get('/', function() use($app) {
 return "Hello World!";
});

$app->post('/bot', function() use($app) {

 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

 if (!$data)
    return 'error';

 if($data->secret !== getenv('VK_SECRET_KEY') && $data->type !== 'confirmation')
    return 'error';

 switch ($data->type)
  {
        case 'confirmation':
            return getenv('VK_CONF');
        break;

        case 'message_new':
            $request_params = array(
                'peer_id' => $data->object->message->from_id,
                'message' => 'Privet',
                'acceses_token' => getenv('VK_TOKEN'),
                'v' => '5.110'
                );
            $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
            file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params);

            return 'ok';
        break;
  }
 return "error";

});

$app->run();
``

Запрос из Callback API

    "type": "message_new",
    "object": {
        "id": 41,
        "date": 1592916860,
        "out": 0,
        "user_id": ...,
        "read_state": 0,
        "title": "",
        "body": "hello",
        "owner_ids": []
    },
    "group_id": ...,
    "event_id": "...",
    "secret": "..."}

Заранее спасибо за ответ.
```

Answer (score 0):

В методе `messages.send` надо дополнительно указать параметр `random_id=0`, сейчас у вас не указан.